How to get the array of input from scenario in gherkin (acceptance - java cucumber) and how to convert the data table into list
Writing step definitions while using array of inputs in Gherkin Acceptance Test(BDD - approach)
Example scenario :- 

Scenario: Assume something 
Given Assume something
When I have 3 numbers "<numbers>" as given below
       | numbers |
       |   1     |
       |   2     |
       |   3     |
Then Assume something

In java code :-
I don't know how to write the step definition for the above scenario without any regex in java code
Could someone write the step definition for the above scenario and change the data table into list of numbers

Does this answer your question? How to pass an array of Integers from Cucumber features file to step definition while writing unit test cases
